# conditions I need to satisfy before running my program

Tags: java, parseint

I have java program that I want to run at the command line as a jar. But before I run my function that processes the data, I have 2 conditions that I need to satisfy. 1. `args[0]` needs to be an integer. 2. There needs to be exactly 2 arguments. If these conditions are not met, I want an error message to pop up and then a system exit. I think I can do #1 right but how would I combine both?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
    try
    {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        process(x, args[1]);    
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.output.println("Please enter an integer");
    }


 }
```

Comment: `args.length` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, here is the code you should write :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if(args == null || args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("You have not entered the required two parameters");
        return;
    }
    try {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        process(x, args[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
    }


}
```

Note that there is a compilation error in your System.output.println("Please enter an integer"); statement, it is rather:

```
System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
```

Comment: This would have the effect of still trying to run the program with invalid arguments(you should return or exit after the first args check fails.

Comment: @javadev do I need a return or system exit at the end of the catch statement too?

Comment: You don't, program will return anyway (last statement in the program). But you do if you have more instructions after your catch blog.

Answer (score 0):

args.length will give you the number of arguments, so add something like

```
if(args.length != 2)
{
  throw new IOException(argumentDescriptionHere);
}
```

Comment: This is sort of nitpicking and just a best practice thing, but why throw an exception that you then have to catch instead of just handling the control flow in the `if`(such as printing the invalid arg message and exiting)

Comment: He defined his main function to throw an IO exception. This is an IO problem, so it seems like it is the OP's intent to throw an exception if there is a problem with IO (such as the arguments passed in).It wouldn't have been my approach either, but I am trying to give the OP what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can do #2 like this:

```
if (args.length < 2)
{
  System.err.println("Need 2 arguments!");
  System.exit(-1)
}
```

Comment: `System.exit(-1)` - NOooooooooooooooooooo ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
    try
    {
        if(args == null || args.length != 2)
        {
           System.out.println("Invalid arguments");
        }
        else{
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            process(x, args[1]);   
        } 
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
    }


 }
```